# Calculate new variable based on existing variables using SAS

Tags: sas, lag, sas-macro

I have been trying to calculate a new field based on existing fields using SAS. I tried lag function but didn't work. Below is the data and program I have tried.

Raw Data: 
Cust_ID Prdct_No no_of_mnths    Actual_Shp_Dt   Count 
x   12  2   8/1/2014    10 
x   12  1   8/11/2014   10 
x   12  0   8/23/2014   10 
y   13  2   8/1/2014    10 
y   13  1   8/11/2014   10 
y   14a 2   8/1/2014    10 
y   14a 1   8/11/2014   10 
y   14a 0   8/21/2014   10 
z   15  3   9/1/2014    20 
z   15  2   9/15/2014   20

Required results: 
Target_Ship_Dt is sum of (lag(Actual_Shp_Dt) and lag(Count)) grouped by Cust_ID and Prdct_No. If Actual_Shp_Dt is late or earlier than target_shp_Dt, then Target_Shp_Dt is SUM(lag(Target_Shp_Dt) and lag(Count)).

Cust_ID Prdct_No no_of_mnths    Actual_Shp_Dt   Count   Target_Ship_Dt 
x   12  2   8/1/2014    10   
x   12  1   8/11/2014   10  8/11/2014 
x   12  0   8/23/2014   10  8/21/2014 
y   13  2   8/1/2014    10   
y   13  1   8/11/2014   10  8/11/2014 
y   14a 2   8/1/2014    10   
y   14a 1   8/11/2014   10  8/11/2014 
y   14a 0   8/21/2014   10  8/21/2014 
z   15  3   9/1/2014    20   
z   15  2   9/15/2014   20  9/21/2014

Code I have tried: 
Data Raw_Data(drop = Prdct_ID_lag Actual_Shp_Dt_lag Count_Lag Target_Shp_Dt1); 
Set Raw_Data; 
By Cust_ID Prdct_ID; 
Prdct_ID_lag = lag(Prdct_ID); 
Format Actual_Shp_Dt_lag date9.; 
Actual_Shp_Dt_lag = lag(Actual_Shp_Dt); 
Count_Lag = lag(Count); 
Format Target_Shp_dt date9.; 
If Prdct_ID ~= Prdct_ID_lag then Actual_Shp_Dt_lag = .; 
If Prdct_ID ~= Prdct_ID_lag then Count_Lag = .; 
Target_Shp_Dt1 = Actual_Shp_Dt_lag + Count_Lag; 
Target_Shp_Dt = Target_Shp_Dt1; 
If Actual_Shp_Dt > Target_Shp_Dt1 Then Target_Shp_Dt = Target_Shp_Dt1 + Count_lag; 
If Actual_Shp_Dt < Target_Shp_Dt1 Then Target_Shp_Dt = Target_Shp_Dt1 + Count_lag; 
Run;

But this code didnt give me right results.

Any help would be appreciated.

After trying new code:
Data have:

Cust_ID Prdct_No no_of_mnths Actual_Shp_Dt Count Target_Ship_Dt 
x 12 2 8/1/2014 10 
x 12 1 8/11/2014 10 8/11/2014 
x 12 0 8/23/2014 10 
y 13 2 8/1/2014 10 
y 13 1 8/11/2014 10 8/11/2014 
y 14a 2 8/1/2014 10  
y 14a 1 8/11/2014 10 8/11/2014 
y 14a 0 8/21/2014 10 8/21/2014 
z 15 3 9/1/2014 20 
z 15 2 9/15/2014 20

Code that worked: 
Data Raw_Data(drop = Prdct_ID_lag Actual_Shp_Dt_lag Count_Lag Target_Shp_Dt1); 
Set Raw_Data; 
By Cust_ID Prdct_ID; 
Cust_ID_lag = lag(Cust_ID); 
Prdct_ID_lag = lag(Prdct_ID); 
Format Actual_Shp_Dt_lag Target_Shp_Dt  date9.; 
Actual_Shp_Dt_lag = lag(Actual_Shp_Dt); 
Count_Lag = lag(Count); 
retain target_shp_dt_lag; 
If Cust_ID = Cust_ID_lag and Prdct_ID = Prdct_ID_lag and  target_shp_dt_lag = . 
Then Target_Shp_Dt = Actual_Shp_Dt_lag + Count_Lag ; 
ELSE IF Cust_ID = Cust_ID_lag and Prdct_ID = Prdct_ID_lag 
Then Target_Shp_Dt = target_shp_dt_lag + Count_Lag ; 
ELSE Target_Shp_Dt = .; 
target_shp_dt_lag = Target_Shp_Dt; 
Run;

Comment: Please could you double check the expected target_shp_dt for the last row in your example data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your definition says that you need to use lag(target_shp_dt) if the initial target_ship_dt isn't equal to actual_shp_dt, but your code never actually does this.

**Update:**

It seems that `lag` doesn't work for variables created in the same data step, but using `retain` does, which is why `Target_Shp_Dt_lag` intially had all missing values.

Also, are you sure about the very last row in your example dataset? It seems to be inconsistent with your rules: lag(count) + lag(actual_shp_dt) = 9/21/2014, but 9/21/2014 > 9/15/2014, so that would mean you'd need to take lag(count) + lag(target_shp_dt), which results in a missing value as lag(target_shp_date) is missing. The code below works for all the other cases.

```
data raw_data;
input Cust_ID :$1. Prdct_No :$3. no_of_mnths :3. Actual_Shp_Dt :mmddyy10. Count :3.;
format actual_shp_dt yymmdd10.;
cards;
x 12 2 8/1/2014 10 
x 12 1 8/11/2014 10 
x 12 0 8/23/2014 10 
y 13 2 8/1/2014 10 
y 13 1 8/11/2014 10 
y 14a 2 8/1/2014 10 
y 14a 1 8/11/2014 10 
y 14a 0 8/21/2014 10 
z 15 3 9/1/2014 20 
z 15 2 9/15/2014 20 
;
run;

data want;
input Cust_ID :$1. Prdct_No :$3. no_of_mnths :3. Actual_Shp_Dt :mmddyy10. Count :3. Target_ship_dt :mmddyy10.;
format actual_shp_dt Target_ship_dt yymmdd10.;
infile cards missover;
cards;
x 12 2 8/1/2014 10 
x 12 1 8/11/2014 10 8/11/2014 
x 12 0 8/23/2014 10 8/21/2014 
y 13 2 8/1/2014 10 
y 13 1 8/11/2014 10 8/11/2014 
y 14a 2 8/1/2014 10 
y 14a 1 8/11/2014 10 8/11/2014 
y 14a 0 8/21/2014 10 8/21/2014 
z 15 3 9/1/2014 20
z 15 2 9/15/2014 20 9/21/2014
;
run;

Data have(drop = Prdct_no_lag Actual_Shp_Dt_lag Count_Lag Target_Shp_Dt1 Target_Shp_Dt_lag) ; 
Set raw_data; 
By Cust_ID Prdct_no; 
Prdct_no_lag = lag(Prdct_no); 
Actual_Shp_Dt_lag = lag(Actual_Shp_Dt); 
Count_Lag = lag(Count); 
retain target_shp_dt_lag;
if first.prdct_no then call missing(Actual_Shp_Dt_lag, count_lag, prdct_no_lag, target_shp_dt_lag);
Target_Shp_Dt1 = Actual_Shp_Dt_lag + Count_Lag; 
Target_Shp_Dt = Target_Shp_Dt1; 
If Actual_Shp_Dt ne Target_Shp_Dt1 Then Target_Shp_Dt = Target_Shp_Dt_lag + Count_lag; 
Target_Shp_Dt_lag = Target_Shp_Dt; 
format Actual_Shp_Dt_lag Target_Shp_dt: yymmdd10.; 
Run; 

proc compare base = want compare = have;
  var Target_Shp_Dt;
run;
```

Comment: Hi.. Thank you very much for the response. I tried above code but didn't work for me. Target_Shp_Dt_lag is totally blank and only few rows of Target_Shp_Dt was populated but sum of Actual_shp_dt and Count_lag...

Comment: It definitely works for me, but perhaps you need to change some of the variable names for compatibility with your existing code?

Comment: Hi, I am using SAS EG 5.1.. When I ran above program as it is with same dataset, I got output that I have pasted in my original question..

Comment: Please could you post the output at the bottom of your question?

Comment: I just added it at thee bottom of my question.. As per your code, Target_Shp_Dt_lag should have some value in it.. but it is completely blank in my output before dropping that variable.. Is that some issue with my SAS version?

Comment: I don't use EG, only base SAS. Are you copying and pasting the entire program, including the input data steps, and getting non-matching results?

Comment: Is there any other way in SAS programming to get this done instead of using lag function? Because I couldn't understand how lag function is working behind..

Comment: I don't think lag works for variables created in the same data step. It should be possible to sort this out using `retain` instead.

Comment: Though above code couldn't satisfy the condition as you mentioned in your answer, retain statement really worked like charm... Please see bottom of my question for little modified code which works for my requirements using retain statement.. Thanks a lot again :)